# Exported function in PowerShell module not available

Tags: powershell, module

I have a simple (for now) module in which I plan to keep various functions that make my life easier. My `.psm1` file currently contains a single function and the `Export-ModuleMember -Function Function-Name` to export it. The `.psd1` file contains the requisite `FunctionsToExport = 'Function-Name'` line.

When I import the module it does not show up as an ExportedCommand in the output of `Get-Module`, even though it shows that it will export that command in the `Get-Module -ListAvailable` output:

```
PS H:\> Get-Module -ListAvailable | ? {$_.Name -eq "Convenience"}


    Directory: \\home\share\My Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules


ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Manifest   1.0.0      Convenience                         Function-Name


PS H:\> Get-Module | ? {$_.Name -eq "Convenience"}

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Manifest   1.0.0      Convenience
```

Any idea how to make my functions available?

Comment: can you do `import-module Convenience -debug -force` and paste output

Comment: @4c74356b41 Sorry I can't get formatting to work properly on that but, the long and short of that is that it does not provide any clues.

Comment: just remove the comment ;) but it is weird that nothing is being outputted. do you actually define the function?

Comment: Yes and I can dot source the `.psm1` file and use my function just fine. Actually, no. I can dot source a `.ps1` file with the same contents and it works.

Comment: Okay, so it's got to be something with my function. I just added a stub `Function Test-Function {}` in my `.psm1` file and that exports properly.

Comment: I found a solution:

I had `[cmdletbinding()]` in my function, which was not strictly necessary (I wasn't doing anything with -Verbose, etc.) and once I removed that and deleted the Manifest so my module is just a Script module, it works fine.

I don't know *why* it wasn't working, but that's a future me problem for when I need to include full on Cmdlets in my module, and maybe by then, someone might have a better answer here.

Answer (score 4):

Defining the `RootModule` in the manifest fixed this problem for me, i.e., in `Convenience.psd1`:

```
# Script module or binary module file associated with this manifest.
RootModule = 'Convenience'

# Functions to export from this module, for best performance, do not use wildcards and do not delete the entry, use an empty array if there are no functions to export.
FunctionsToExport = @(
    Function-Name
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how\what exactly happens, but in my modules I was using this trick in my psm file:

```
ls $scriptRoot\*.ps1 -recurse | foreach { . $_.FullName }
Export-ModuleMember -Function a, b, c
```

where a, b, and c are cmdlets, not functions.

Comment: To clarify this, you stored your function declarations in ps1 files inside your Module's directory and subdirectories and dot sourced them with this and exported them?

Comment: yeah, and a,b,c are in different files in the module